when running flutter doctor command on cmd it closes instantly, and when running it on the powerShell gives the error in the image?
I'am newly installed flutter and every time I run the flutter doctor command this error shows up
enter image description here
and when I try to run the same command on the normal cmd it closes instantly, also I added the correct paths in the env variables
enter image description here
can any one help me??
I added the correct paths in the env variables
enter image description here
can any one help me??

it happens when system isn't as per requirement of platform
